# Gatsby Head API not present in source code

Tags: gatsby

I try to add information to my Head using Gatsby.
I followde the instructions on Gatsby setup uding the Head API:

For my file pages/index.tsx

```
export const Head = () => {
    return <>
        <html lang="fr"/>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </>
}
```

I have try different syntax and to upgrade Gatsby to the 5.12.4. But the lang='fr' is never present in my source code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Without more information it's hard to figure out what the problem might be. I have a small [sample repository](https://gitlab.com/datawookie/gatsby-whimsyweb/-/tree/23-head-api) that implements three approaches to using the Head API (look at the `23-head-api` branch). There's also a short blog post [here](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/01/humble-head/) that might help.

If you can share more of your code I'd be happy to help figure out the problem. Can you share a stripped-down repository?